# For a Riemannian metric $g=dr^2+q(r)d\theta^2$, is $r$ always the distance from a point?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $(r,\theta)$ be smooth coordinates on a connected open neighbourhood $U$ of a surface, $r>0$. Suppose we have a Riemannian metric given by
$$g=dr^2+q(r)d\theta^2,$$

where $q(r)$ is a smooth positive function.

Is it true that $r+c_0$ is the distance function from some point $p$ on the surface?

---

**Here is what I know:**

$\nabla r=\partial_r$, so $r$ satisfies the Eikonal equation $|\nabla r|=1$. One can prove (this is a known result) that there exists a one-dimensional embedded submanifold $\Sigma \subseteq U$, such that
$$
r(x)=r_{\pm}^{\Sigma}(x)+r_0,
$$
where $r_{\pm}^{\Sigma}$ is the signed distance from $\Sigma=r^{-1}(r_0)$.

Is it true that $\Sigma=S_p(r_1)=\{ x \, | \, d(x,p)=r_1\}$ for some $p \in \bar U$ and $r_1>0$?

Note that $p$ does not need to be in $U$. The picture I have in my mind is that of a Euclidean disk where $g=dr^2+r^2d\theta$, and the point $p$ is the origin of the disk; the polar coordinates are not well-defined at $p$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the cylinder $\mathbb{R}\times S^1$ endowed with the metric
$$
g = \mathrm{d}r^2 + \left(\cosh r\right)^2 \mathrm{d}\theta^2,
$$
where $\mathrm{d}\theta$ is the natural metric on the circle $S^1 = \mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}$. Then $r$ is the projection on the first factor, but is not the distance to any point $p \in \mathbb{R}\times S^1$. However, $r$ is the (signed) distance to the circle $C_0 = \{0\}\times S^1 \subset \mathbb{R}\times S^1$.

Comment: Thanks, this is an interesting example. Can you please say why did you use the factor $(\cosh r)^2$? Couldn't you just take the "standard" cylinder where the metric is $g=dr^2+d\theta^2$?

Comment: One of the many parametrizations (here, called *by horospheres*) of the hyperbolic plane has a metric of the form $\mathrm{d}r^2 + \cosh(r)^2 \mathrm{d}t^2$ (or something like that). IIjust  adapted this example so that the fiber $r= \mathrm{cst}$ are compact and look like the polar coordinates.

Answer (score 3):

Even in the case you are considering, the result is false : consider the euclidean plane without the origin $M = \mathbb R^2 \backslash \{0\}$ in polar coordinates. Then, $r$ is not a distance function from a point in the manifold.

For the result to hold, you will need to add some geodesic completeness hypothesis